# Delegation not updating the array

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm trying to implement the delegation pattern on Swift. I have a main view controller and a "addInvoiceViewController" view controller which shows up when tapped on the plus button. I want to modify a list in the main view controller when tapped on a button in the "addInvoiceViewController".

Here is how I coded the main view controller (I inherited my protocol correctly) :

```
func addInvoice(name: String) {
    invoices.append(name)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! addInvoiceViewController
    vc.delegate = self

}
```

Here is my "addInvoiceViewController" :

```
protocol AddInvoice: class {
    func addInvoice(name: String)
}

class addInvoiceViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: AddInvoice?

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func addInvoiceButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if textField.text != "" {
            delegate?.addInvoice(name: textField.text!)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

But the list hasn't been modified when tapped on the button (I know it  because the list is connected to a tableview which shows the strings contained in the list)

I added the breakpoint in the viewDidLoad and checked what was delegate and here it is :

[breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLpZ4.png)

Here is cellFOrRowAt :

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return invoicesSectionTitles.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let invoiceKey = invoicesSectionTitles[section]
        if let invoiceValues = invoicesDictionary[invoiceKey] {
            return invoiceValues.count
        }
        return 0
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let invoiceKey = invoicesSectionTitles[indexPath.section]

        if let invoiceValues = invoicesDictionary[invoiceKey] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = invoiceValues[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return invoicesSectionTitles[section]
    }

    func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return invoicesSectionTitles
    }
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint in viewDidLoad - is the delegate nil ?

Comment: How adding a breakpoint helps to find out if the delegate is nil ?

Comment: Because it will show the state of all your properties, and you can check that the delegate has been set as you expect.  Or just add a print statement in viewDidLoad to print the delegate to see if its nil.  Work through your code logically with breakpoints or print statements to see what is happening.

Comment: I added a photo of the data given by the breakpoint. But how do you print the delegate because I don't have a variable called delegate.

Comment: Check viewDidLoad in your AddInvoiceViewController

Comment: Ok, I updated it. It isn't nil I think.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in `tableView` setup. Are you sure that you setup `tableView.delegate` and `tableView.dataSource`? Does it show anything when you put some random data in `invoices` array ? You can also print the `name` value inside `addInvoice` function in `mainViewController` to check if it runs so you'll know if the problem is in `tableView` or `protocol`

Comment: Yes it show the data contained by the list

Comment: @m4thus4n solved your query ??

Comment: Not yet ! I can't show the newly added.

Comment: please add your cellForRow method

Comment: I added it in the question.

Comment: It appears that your cellForRow is using values from a dictionary, yet your delegate is appending the name to a different array.

Comment: Have you verified that addInvoiceButton is called? Maybe you forgot to link it to your button? :)